# Heat, Work and Internal energy in closed systems

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation, work

This has been troubling me for a while now. I know that the performed work equals $P\Delta V$ for isobaric systems and I know that in isochoric systems no work is done, but how do I find the heat $Q$? I keep seeing that they both equal $nRT$, but that seems counter-intuitive considering there are instances where the work does not equal the heat. To help formulate your answer, I am using the form of the first law equation $\Delta U = Q + W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work done is the area under the p vs V graph.

Once you have found $W$, you need to find the change in internal energy.

The internal energy at any given point is simply $U=(3/2)nRT$

By calculating the internal energy before and after the process, you find $\Delta U$ to be the difference between the two. From here, it is straightforward to find the heat energy supplied.